# Book I read about 10 years ago; it has a black cat’s face with green eyes

Tags: story-identification, books, witches

The book was about a girl who was suspicious of a certain person where she stayed. She was always seen at a particular time of day, and always had her cat with her. After a while the witch got suspicious of the little girl and sent the cat to stalk her. One day she and her friends tricked the cat and caught it and put it in a cage... 
There was a reference to the witch's house being shaped like an octagon or pentagon or one of the gons I don't remember.

There was something about the girl being caught in the attic because she and her friend went to search the witches house for something but they took too long  and she or her friend had to use white chalk to draw a circle around her to save herself from being touched or killed by the witch. It was a fantasy or fictional book. It was also part of a trilogy.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: This vaguely sounds like a children's version of H.P. Lovecraft's [The Dreams in the Witch House](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/dwh.aspx).

Comment: no it's not it unfortunately.